# Inline-Block Position to the left and Inline-Block position to the right - Same Line

Tags: html, css

On the same line, I want to have one inline-block element positioned to the left of the page and other inline-block element position to the right.

So far, I have this:

HTML

```
<div class="left-nav">
    <a href="">RcJane</a>
</div>

<div class="right-nav">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Available</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right-nav{ background:#6699FF; }
.left-nav{  background:#0066CC; }
.right-nav,.left-nav{   display: inline-block;  }
```

Should I use floats? 
[CodePen with Floats](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DoEfH)

Comment: @j08691 I ended up using floats. If I use floats, do I need to display inline-block? Seems like I don't need that code anymore

Comment: No, floats don't require inline-block elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.right-nav { background:#6699FF; float: right; }
.left-nav { background:#0066CC; float: left; }
```

Seems good. You may have to clear the floats afterwards:

```
<div class="left-nav">
    <a href="">RcJane</a>
</div>

<div class="right-nav">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Available</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>

<br style="clear: both;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I completely forgot, I can use the clearfix hack.

Comment: Other clearing floats solutions are available http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Is `overflow: auto` really that good? My colleague is using it wildly.

Comment: Never claimed "bestness"! Simply pointing out there are several ways to skin a cat, they all have shortcomings in my mind. adding a div puts layout into the markup and overflow:auto isn't very intuitive